# Python for loop parameters

Tags: python, jes

Hi im just wondering what the 4 would do in this code

```
for y in range(0, height, 4):
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the documentation for `range` should explain that. Did you try looking it up?

Comment: yep its out of a book and they didnt explain

Comment: The python _documentation_ is available online. Did you try looking it up?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) is the documentation for `range`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range. it's the step (optional parameter). you probably should start to use google.

Comment: yes i have i couldnt find what the third value meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 in the range function used in the for loop indicates the increment step. suppose the value of height is 20. Then the values for y will be set as 0, 0+4=4, 4+4=8, ... till 20 in subsequent iterations of the for loop.

For a more detailed description of range function check out the python documentation at:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: the 4 is a value in the "range" call - and both are not _part_ of Python's `for` statement - you could clarify that.

Comment: That is why I had included the python documentation for range. I will edit the answer to reflect it better.

Answer (score 3):

Range with just one parameter: end.

Range with two parameters: start, end.

Range with three parameters: start, end, step.

So in your specific case

```
 for y in range(0, height, 4)
```

0, 4, 8, ..., n, where n < height.

Answer (score 1):

plus 4 each time you hit the range.
For example,

```
 for y in range(0, 14, 4)
```

you will get 0, 4, 8, 12